# JasperReports: How to pass parameter to subReport

Tags: jasper-reports

How to pass parameter to sub report in `JasperReports`?

I'm able to pass the parameter to master report but I'm not able pass parameter to its sub report.

Can any one give me the solution for it?

Answer (score 38):

Try using [iReport](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/project/project_home.php?projectname=ireport) if you are not.

When viewing a report within iReport you can select the properties of the subreport within the main report.

In this there is an option in `Subreport properties` called `Parameters`. Using this you can pass parameters to your subreport.

- Select this and click the `Add`
  button.
- Then click the button right of the
  `Value expression` Box
- Next an option screen will pop up
  where you can select the parameter
  from the master report you want to
  pass.

If you want to do it via xml here's a quick example.

```
<subreport>
    <subreportParameter name="XML_ID">
        <subreportParameterExpression>
            <![CDATA[$P{MASTER_REPORT_PARAMETER}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
    </subreportParameter>
</subreport>
```

Comment: Note: you also have to define matching parameters in the sub-report.

Comment: A note here. My subreport parameter wasn't working when I had just: <subreportParameter name="SUB_REPORT_PARAM"/>. Adding subreportParameterExpression fixed the problem.