# passing parameter from main report to subReport According To Row in JasperSoft iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JasperReports: How to pass parameter to subReport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310188/jasperreports-how-to-pass-parameter-to-subreport)

I have one sub Report inside the main Report. Now I have to pass parameter from the mainReport to the sub Report. I have uploaded an image to make it clear. As shown in the image I have to pass the loanId as the parameter to the subReport. I have used a parameter named Id which holds the value of the LoanId of the main Report. The parameter Id keeps changing according to the main Report's LoanId data and I have used this parameter in the where Condition of the subReport. How is it possible to pass the parameter which changes according to row from the main report to the sub report. Thanks .. ![image]

Comment: @Alex it is similar but it is a little different since it is about passing a Field from the main report to the subreport instead of passing the a Parameter from the main report to the subreport. Although just a letter different.

Comment: This is about passing a row field, not parameter in general - vote to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the field name is `LoanId` in the main report and the parameter in the subreport is called `P_LOAN_ID` (just so they are different) it would look like:

```
<subreport>
    <subreportParameter name="P_LOAN_ID">
        <subreportParameterExpression>
            <![CDATA[$F{LoanId}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
    </subreportParameter>
</subreport>
```

Comment: And this is easy to do (if not quite as obvious as one might hope) in iReport.

Comment: @mdahlman well if you add an already created report as a subreport, instead of clicking new, it will prompt you to supply the parameter values that defined in the subreport. The fields in the main report are listed there along with the parameters in the main report.