# How do access main report field in sub report

Tags: jasper-reports

I have field in main report (*hasRole.toString()*). I want to use this field in sub report.

How do i access in sub report?

Comment: You should use the subreport parameters. For more details look at [this post](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/subreport/index.html#subreports)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JasperReports: How to pass parameter to subReport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310188/jasperreports-how-to-pass-parameter-to-subreport)