# How to merge two jrxml jasper reports into a one single pdf output file

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have two JRXML File with two different data source. 
in first jasper report data source is JRXmlDataSource and in second jasper report data source is JRResultSetDataSource

```
try
{
            conn= objConnector.getConnection();
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);

            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareCall("{ call Sp_DEMO(?) }");
            ps.setString(1,condition);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            JasperReport jreport1 = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("d:\\JRXML\\ECGImage.jrxml");
            JasperPrint jprint1 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jreport1, new HashMap(), new JRResultSetDataSource(rs));
            jprintlist.add(jprint1);
            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("d:\\JRXML\\RadiologyReport.jrxml");

                JRXmlDataSource xmlDataSource = new JRXmlDataSource("d:\\abc.xml"+, "/X-RayReport/Type");
                JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, new HashMap(),xmlDataSource);
                jprintlist.add(jasperPrint);


            File file = new File("d:\\demo.pdf");
            if(file.exists())
            {
                file.delete();
            }
            JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
            exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, jprintlist);
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File("d:\\demo.pdf"));
            exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, output);
            exporter.exportReport();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

i want to create single pdf file as output from both jrxml file.

Answer (score 2):

You can merge the above two pdf like this

```
List pages = jasperPrint.getPages();
for (int j = 0; j < pages.size(); j++) {
   JRPrintPage object = (JRPrintPage)pages.get(j);
   jprint1.addPage(object);
}
```

And `jprint1` will be your single output .

Answer (score 1):

Well, that is what *JasperReport Subreports* are meant to do. You have to create another `.jrxml` which would be the master report, and include the other existing two in this one as "*Subreports*". So you'll have a single output.

To create subreports (if you don't know), please refer to these tutoriale: [JasperReports - Create SubReports](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jasper_reports/jasper_create_subreports.htm),   [SubReports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/subreports).

From the fact that you have two different data sources, I think that you might as well need to read this too: [Pass parameter to subreports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310188/jasperreports-how-to-pass-parameter-to-subreport).

You might need this to pass the different data sources as parameters to the subreports, thus not in your `JasperPrint` object instance.

Answer (score 0):

I have no factual defence or argumentation about how I do it normally and all that is just matter of personal preference and the ease that I have during the merging and post-processing stages for adding some general additional stuff to the merged report i.e. page numbers, header, footer, etc.

The correct jasper-report way is to stay away from joining reports in Java and instead, to make a main report and then adding subreports to it. However, if you really want to do that in Java, you can use markers and afterwards post-process everything again, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42426312/18397507).

***Still, I just don't do that.***

Most of the time I prefer to first generate and export different sections of my final report in pdf separately and afterward merge them all together utilizing [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/). By not following the jasper report's way, usually I avoid a hell of subreports hierarchy as normally each section of the final report on their own contain couple of other subreports. So, I just find it better to focus on each section separately and later doing the final merging.

I normally do something like this:

```
public final class Report
{
    List<File> MergingFiles;
    ReportData data;

    public Report(ReportData data)
    {
        // I prefer to pack all the data like, jrxml files path or 
        // the data that fills the report in a separate object -> ReportData
        this.data = data;
        MergingFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private void generateCoverPage() throws JRException
    {
        /* Setting up the data which needs to be passed to cover page
           reading the cover page jrxml file
           compiling the report */
        // and Exporting - I normally use JRPdfExporter for that
       exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(data.getCoverPageExportPath()));
       exporter.exportReport();
       MergingFiles.add(new File(data.getCoverPageExportPath()));
    }

    private void generateSecondPart() throws JRException
    {
        /* similar to generateCoverPage() to create another part of the report */
    }
    
    public void generateReport()
    {
        generateCoverPage();
        generateSecondPart();
        mergePDFFiles(MergingFiles, data.getPrintFileName());
        /* Do additional general post process i.e. page numbers, header, footer, etc. here 
           and then clean up temp files */ 
    }

    private void mergePDFFiles(List<File> files, String mergedFileName) 
    {
        // all classes are imported from "org.apache.pdfbox"
        try 
        {
            PDFMergerUtility pdfmerger = new PDFMergerUtility();
            for (File file : files) 
            {
                PDDocument document;
                document = PDDocument.load(file);
                pdfmerger.setDestinationFileName(mergedFileName);
                pdfmerger.addSource(file);
                pdfmerger.mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly());
                document.close();
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error to merge files. Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

`//` are just my side notes, however comments surrender with `/* */` are the parts which you have to take care of them in case that you wanted to use my approach.