# How to access private and protected JRElements members of JasperDesign object?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am creating Jasper object using JasperDesign class and initiating it using JRXmlLoader from jrxml file.
 
I am extracting all the JRBands using `getAllBands()` method to get all JRBands and from each band, I am extracting JRElements using method `getElements()` of JRBand.

However, after getting each element like `staticField` or `textField`, I am not able to get their values from "TEXT" field which is private or protected.

How can I access these values?

Comment: You should post the code - to reproduce the issue

Comment: @AlexK  This is not an issue. JRElements class doesn't have a getter for its text value. Since  Jasper library is an open source library, Could I create my own getter to get it? if yes then how?

Comment: `Since Jasper library is an open source library, Could I create my own getter to get it?` - Yes. You can do everything you want. It is Java

Comment: @AlexK Question is how? The library is too big to make any changes.

Comment: There is no need to make any changes to the library, I think I have understood your question, you just need to cast the `JRElement` to relative `JRDesign` class, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast the `JRElement` to the relative JRDesign class to be able to access the specific attributes of the element:

- `<textField>` to [`JRDesignTextField`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/design/JRDesignTextElement.html)
- `<staticText>` to [`JRDesignStaticText`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/design/JRDesignStaticText.html)

## Example

**jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="testJasperDesign" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="597c0716-df6b-42ec-a7c8-863eb1b7174a">
    <parameter name="testParam" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["Hello world"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <variable name="variable1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <title>
        <band height="32" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="bf5a8f35-3faf-457b-a6fc-b29d97a9c332"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{testParam}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="59922664-93a3-4f69-a906-5ff418d09cd3"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Static text]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

**Java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JRException {

    JasperDesign design = JRXmlLoader.load("jasper/testJasperDesign.jrxml");
    JRBand titleBand = design.getTitle();
    JRElement[] elements = titleBand.getElements();
    for (JRElement element : elements) {
        if (element instanceof JRDesignTextField){
            JRDesignTextField textField = (JRDesignTextField) element;
            JRExpression expression = textField.getExpression();
            System.out.println(expression.getText());
        }
        if (element instanceof JRDesignStaticText){
            JRDesignStaticText staticText = (JRDesignStaticText) element;
            System.out.println(staticText.getText());
        }

    }
}
```

**Output**

> $P{testParam} 
> Static text

Comment: Perfect answer. It's Working for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hello Petter,
From where to get the expression value(after evaluation) of text field after calling a fillReport() method of jasperfillmanager. I am populating it with java bean source.

Comment: @SaurabhSonkar sorry I can't really understand the question, the JasperDesign is before you fill (hence no values from datasource), after you fill you have the JasperPrint (no more bands), but from here you can get the final result text.

Comment: This post shows how you can iterate a JasperPrint https://stackoverflow.com/a/42426312/5292302, it finds a certain JRPrintText and changes it

Comment: You got it right but I'm not using pages. My all content is in a band like a title, summary, detail 1, detail 2 etc.
Can I iterate through this JasperPrint object?

Comment: Check the link in previous commet, the answer does exactly that

Comment: @SaurabhSonkar JasperPrint has nothing to do with details sections, title sections ecc, it's the final print so it has only pages and JRPrintElement's, if you have 0 pages, that means that your report is empty (note you need to call this after your fill your report)