# How to get total Page count of a combined report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I've a jrxml and through java I'm setting a `List<List<?>>` in the bean collection. Now, my final list has 5 lists(can be more than 5 also), so the jrxml is treating all as different report in a single report and I can't get the combined page count of the report. The report shows page 1-5 for all the 5 reports.

Note: I saw some answers where its says to get count of pafe from backend, but in my case, its not feasible since the jasper printing is out of our coding feasibility. Is there a way this can be achieved from JRXML side?
TIA.

```
<textField evaluationTime="Master">
    <reportElement x="660" y="14" width="58" height="14" forecolor="#1A75B4" uuid="24876562-c6ab-424d-9ac6-769ef9b54079">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
    </reportElement>
    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
        <font fontName="Albany WT" size="10"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page " + $V{MASTER_CURRENT_PAGE}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
<textField evaluationTime="Master">
        <reportElement x="725" y="14" width="50" height="14" forecolor="#1A75B4" uuid="5c06c90b-79f2-450b-9f43-7eb00676871b">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
        </reportElement>
        <textElement textAlignment="Left">
            <font fontName="Albany WT" size="10"/>
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" of " + $V{MASTER_TOTAL_PAGES}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

**Edit 2 (Added Jasper Print code) Here helperReturnObject is a List of List**:

```
List<JasperPrint> prints = new ArrayList<JasperPrint>();
        helperReturnObject.getTemPlatepaths().forEach(t -> {
            try
            {
                int index = helperReturnObject.getTemPlatepaths().indexOf(t);
                JasperReport jasperReport = null;

                if (!developMentFlag)
                {
                    jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(JasperGatewayClass.class.getResourceAsStream(t));
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(new FileInputStream(new File("path")));
                    }
                    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                    {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(
                        helperReturnObject.getBeanCollections().get(index));
                JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,
                        helperReturnObject.getParameters().get(index), dataSource);
                prints.add(jasperPrint);
            }
            catch (/*JRException | NullPointerException*/ Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage() + "----------------------ERROR----------------");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```

**Final Edit Edit 3(Working now. Had to update the code in order to get it worked for page header band):**

```
for (JasperPrint jp : prints)
        {
            List<JRPrintPage> pages = jp.getPages();
            // Loop all pages of report
            for (JRPrintPage jpp : pages)
            {
                List<JRPrintElement> elements = jpp.getElements();
                // Loop all elements on page
                for (JRPrintElement jpe : elements)
                {
                    System.out.println(jpe.getClass().getTypeName());
                    // Check if text element
                    if (jpe instanceof JRTemplatePrintFrame)
                    {
                        JRTemplatePrintFrame jpf = (JRTemplatePrintFrame) jpe;
                        List<JRPrintElement> jpeElements = jpf.getElements();
                        for (JRPrintElement jpeElement : jpeElements)
                        {
                            if (jpeElement instanceof JRTemplatePrintText)
                            {
                                JRTemplatePrintText jpt = (JRTemplatePrintText) jpeElement;
                                // Check if current page marker
                                if (CURRENT_PAGE_NUMBER.equals(jpt.getValue()))
                                {
                                    jpt.setText("Page " + currentPage + " of"); // Replace marker
                                    continue;
                                }
                                // Check if total page marker
                                if (TOTAL_PAGE_NUMBER.equals(jpt.getValue()))
                                {
                                    jpt.setText(" " + totPageNumber); // Replace marker
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                currentPage++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Correct if I'm wrong but from my understanding you have a main report and inside of it 5 subreports displaying some data from inner lists - is that correct? If so, where are you refering to the page count, in the main report or in the subreports? Try using variables `MASTER_CURRENT_PAGE` and `MASTER_TOTAL_PAGES` with evaluation time on the field set to master.

Comment: Your question is unclear if it's all in one report, you either do what Amongalen suggested or move pageNumber to main report, if multiple different reports this is related https://stackoverflow.com/q/42426311/5292302

Comment: @Amongalen : There is only one report. From java, I'm sending a List of List. The list of list has size 5. Jasper is treating each list as a different report. I tried MASTER_TOTAL_PAGES setting evaluation to master, its still showing page 1-5 for each report. See the edit.

Comment: @PetterFriberg, Like I said changing *JasperPrint* is out of code feasibility.

Comment: "There is only one report", this is unclear, you are not using subreports?, are you using the jr:list component, I think you need to supply a [mcve] for us to understand your issue

Comment: @PetterFriberg, added the code for jasper. I don't have much expertise on jasper coding & how it works. can you please check & let me know how this can be achieved.

Comment: ok great, so you are generating multiple reports in java, you need to use a solution as in comment that I passed previously [How to recalculate page number when combining multiple jasper reports in export?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42426311/5292302). Either post elaborate or pass current page number as parameter, see the different answers

Comment: this is working in footer band. But my requirement is to show page number in the page header. Can you please provide an update?

Comment: Had to update code. Now its working. See the edit 3

Comment: You should pass the solution in answer instead as an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the page number is inside detail band or footer, the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42426311/how-to-recalculate-page-number-when-combining-multiple-jasper-reports-in-export) will work. But since my requirement was to add the page number in page header, I had to update the code.

```
for (JasperPrint jp : prints)
    {
        List<JRPrintPage> pages = jp.getPages();
        // Loop all pages of report
        for (JRPrintPage jpp : pages)
        {
            List<JRPrintElement> elements = jpp.getElements();
            // Loop all elements on page
            for (JRPrintElement jpe : elements)
            {
                System.out.println(jpe.getClass().getTypeName());
                // Check if text element
                if (jpe instanceof JRTemplatePrintFrame)
                {
                    JRTemplatePrintFrame jpf = (JRTemplatePrintFrame) jpe;
                    List<JRPrintElement> jpeElements = jpf.getElements();
                    for (JRPrintElement jpeElement : jpeElements)
                    {
                        if (jpeElement instanceof JRTemplatePrintText)
                        {
                            JRTemplatePrintText jpt = (JRTemplatePrintText) jpeElement;
                            // Check if current page marker
                            if (CURRENT_PAGE_NUMBER.equals(jpt.getValue()))
                            {
                                jpt.setText("Page " + currentPage + " of"); // Replace marker
                                continue;
                            }
                            // Check if total page marker
                            if (TOTAL_PAGE_NUMBER.equals(jpt.getValue()))
                            {
                                jpt.setText(" " + totPageNumber); // Replace marker
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            currentPage++;
        }
    }
```