# Map Bind Variables to Sub Reports with a Dynamic Where Clause in Jasper Reports

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have a parent report with a dynamic where clause, which is passed as $P!{WHERE_CLAUSE}, and the where clause in turn contains $P{} parameters

**Eg: $P!{WHERE_CLAUSE}=> where docno between $P{P_FROMDOCNO} and $P{P_TODOCNO}**

Values for $P{P_FROMDOCNO} and $P{P_TODOCNO} are also passed in the same execution

The parent report has a subreport, that summarizes based on certain category, whose query is based on the parent's where clause.

**select vat,sum(amt) from tablename $P!{WHERECLAUSE} order by vat**

So the where clause is passed to the sub-report using parameter mapping. But the subreport fails to read $P{P_FROMDOCNO} and $P{P_TODOCNO} values from the parent, resulting in empty document. All the above parameters have been mapped to the subreport parameters. The main goal is to fire the query in the database with bind parameters, even for the sub reports.

Kindly let me know if any solution for the above.

*Edit: My question is not a duplicate of the mentioned question in the comments section. Because my subreport receives all the mapped parameter values, but the dynamic where clause($P!{WHERECLAUSE_SUB} which has the $P{P_FROMDOCNO} and $P{P_TODOCNO} fails to evaluate.*

Thanks in advance,

Geetha

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JasperReports: How to pass parameter to subReport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310188/jasperreports-how-to-pass-parameter-to-subreport)

Comment: Sorry. I am closing the question as the parameters work fine, I was having a data issue. Just checked the logs and fixed it. Thanks!